# Как переходить на модальное окно закрыв родителя и вернуться обратно?

Tags: javascript, html, окно

Нужно открыть модальное окно чтобы получить значение, знаю как. Но нужно чтобы потом вернулось(после нажатия кнопки) то же родительское окно!

На модальное окно перехожу по ссылке:

```
<a href=m3_1.php target="_blank"  onclick="window.open(this.href,this.target,'width= 370,height=300');return false;">Найти</a>
```

Работает.

Пытаюсь вернуться через обработчик:

```
onclick="window.open('index.php', 'resizable=yes, location=yes,  scrollbars=yes, toolbar=yes, menubar=yes, width=1200, height=800, scrollbars=no');"
```

И тут надо, чтобы:

1. Родительская страница открывалась на весь монитор;
2. Не было 2 открытых родительских окна;
3. Закрывалось модальное окно;
4. Преемлю HTML, java script.

Comment: Ссылка на главной странице, которая работает: <a href=m3_1.php target="_blank"  onclick="window.open(this.href,this.target,'width= 370,height=300');return false;">Найти</a>

Comment: _Нужно открыть модальное окно чтобы получить значение, знаю как. Но нужно чтобы потом вернулось(после нажатия кнопки) то же родительское окно!_ вообще ничего не понял. можно более подробнее?

Comment: Звучит так, как будто это один из тех сайтов которые в России блокируют .... Если по теме, то: зачем открывать по новой "родительское окно", если можно просто закрыть "модальное" через `window.close()`? Каким образом может открыться 2 "родительских" окна, если "модальное окно" должно закрываться?